# Find Android version on S6 - suspect Android 7 because of rounded icons

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-6, android-versions

I recently updated my Samsung S6. As far as I can tell, because I'm now seeing rounded app icons, I'm now using Android 7 with the Samsung Experience UX, based on this post:

www.sammobile.com/2017/03/09/galaxy-s6-edge-running-android-7-0-nougat-pictures/

How can I confirm the Android version without installing a helper app that does this? There's no *settings > about phone* and I'm not seeing it under *settings > about device*, or *settings > developer options*

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

Settings > about device > software info